# apache showing directory structure of my rails app when using a directory setup for multiple rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache

I have this on my httpd.conf

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/passenger-4.0.42/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so 
PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/passenger-4.0.42 
PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.1/ruby 

RackEnv development

<VirtualHost *:3000>
    ServerName [ip]
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/apps
    <Directory /var/www/html/apps>
        AllowOverride all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>

    RackBaseURI /app1
    <Directory /var/www/html/apps/app1/public>
        AllowOverride all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>

    RackBaseURI /app2
    <Directory /var/www/html/apps/app2/public>
        AllowOverride all
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Accessing `[ip]:3000/app1` or `[ip]:3000/app2` just shows the directory structure and not running the rails app. But if I try using with just a single project like below

```
LoadModule passenger_module /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/passenger-4.0.42/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so 
PassengerRoot /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/passenger-4.0.42 
PassengerDefaultRuby /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.1/ruby 

RackEnv development

<VirtualHost *:3000>
     ServerName [ip]
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/apps/app1/public
     <Directory /var/www/html/apps/app1/public>
         AllowOverride all
         Options -MultiViews
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Accessing `[ip]:3000` works just fine.